# Complex inverse Fourier transform when using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I am using MATLAB and I am trying to find the ifft of a symmetric function, but I keep getting a complex result. I have tried using circshift, but I can't seem to get it figured out.

How can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
t = 0:0.001:0.119;

for i = 1:120

    comp1(i) = 9.8*cos(2*pi*200*t(i));

    comp2(i) = 7.6*cos(2*pi*145*t(i) + 30/57.3);

    comp3(i) = 5.4*cos(2*pi*93*t(i) + 70/57.3);

    comp4(i) = 3.2*cos(2*pi*58*t(i) + 160/57.3);

    comp5(i) = cos(2*pi*35*t(i) + 320/57.3);

    YS = comp1 + comp2 + comp3 + comp4 + comp5;
end

Q = 1000/(2*60)*[-59:1:60];

Box = [zeros(1, 40), ones(1, 5), zeros(1, 30), ones(1, 5), zeros(1, 40)];

Box1 = circshift(Box, [0, 60]);

F = ifft(Box1);
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `YS` and `Q` in your example? they are not used in the expression for `Box`

Comment: First of all, `fft` is padding your vector such that it is getting a length of `2^n`. Then note that `ifft([1,0,0,1])` does not output a real result.

Comment: @flawr, Matlab's `fft` does not do zero-padding unless you tell it to.

Comment: @ItamarKatz Oh right, sorry, for that.

Answer (score 0):

(I am not sure what `YS` and `Q` in your code are for, so I just ignore them).

The transform `X` of a real signal `x` of length `N` has the property that

```
X(k) = X(N-k)*
```

for `k=1,...,N-1`, where `*` is complex conjugate. For a real transform (as in your example) you can just ignore the `*`. Note that the indexing goes from `0` to `N-1`, so for `k=0` the above property is not defined, since the index of the last term is `N-1` (there is no `X(N)`).

In your case the signal `Box` does not have this property, nor does `Box1` (check it!). Try for example:

```
Box = [zeros(1,41),ones(1,5),zeros(1,29),ones(1,5),zeros(1,40)];
```

This signal *does* have this property, and its `ifft` is indeed real.